# ruby if the input is the key then print the value

Tags: ruby

I'm trying ruby and I'd like to ask for user input if the input matches a value then print the key out... How do I do that?

something like:

```
numbers = { 1 => :one, 2 => :two, 3 => :three, 4=> :four, 5 => :five, 6=> :six, 7=> :seven, 8 => :eight, 9=> :nine  };

input = gets.chomp
case input
when 1
then #print the related value
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Your example is bad, because it does just the opposite as you wrote at the beginning.

Comment: Why so fussy? You get the sense right? key value, value key It doesn't matter to me. If i got the method and the correct way I can just translate it to key or value ....Also thanks for your time

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you need to print key do this:

```
numbers = { 1 => :one, 2 => :two, 3 => :three, 4=> :four, 5 => :five, 6=> :six, 7=> :seven, 8 => :eight, 9=> :nine  }

puts gets.chomp.to_i
# 1
# => nil
```

If you need to print value for the key do this:

```
numbers = { 1 => :one, 2 => :two, 3 => :three, 4=> :four, 5 => :five, 6=> :six, 7=> :seven, 8 => :eight, 9=> :nine  }

puts numbers[ gets.chomp.to_i ]
# 1
# one
# => nil
```

The same but this the default value print out:

```
numbers = { 1 => :one, 2 => :two, 3 => :three, 4=> :four, 5 => :five, 6=> :six, 7=> :seven, 8 => :eight, 9=> :nine  }

puts ( numbers[ gets.chomp.to_i ] || "The key isn't found" )

# 10
# The key isn't found"
# => nil
```

Also, please refer to [Ruby Wiki Book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming).

Comment: This is functionally correct. However, you can use Hash#fetch instead of relying on || and nil's falsyness. `numbers.fetch(key)` will raise KeyError if the key is not contained within the hash, or can be supplied an argument to return instead: `haystack.fetch(needle, :tumbleweed)`.

Comment: downvotes how can I improve the answer?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand, you need to search for a value in hash, and then return the corresponding key.

```
numbers = { 1 => :one, 2 => :two, 3 => :three, 4=> :four, 5 => :five, 6=> :six, 7=> :seven, 8 => :eight, 9=> :nine  }
input = :three

numbers.key input # returns 3
```

If you want to search for the user input, replace the second line with:

```
input = gets.chomp.to_sym
```